# Prototype or JQuery change the value of a hidden field?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I'm having some trouble with prototype changing the value of a hidden field.

Function:

```
function remove_fields (link) {
    $(link).next('input[type=hidden]').value = '';
    $(link).up(".open_hours").hide();
}
```

If I comment out the `$(link).next('input[type=hidden]').value = '';` the hide function works. Trying to set the value gives me an error:

```
$(link).next("input[type=hidden]") is undefined
```

Here is my HTML around the function call:

```
    <div class="monday">

        <div class ="open_hours">
            <li><label for="location_monday">Monday</label>
            Open: 06:29PM - 
            Close: 04:21PM 
            <a href="#" onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;">remove</a></li>

            <li class="hidden optional" id="location_monday_open_input"><input id="location_monday_open" name="location[monday_open]" type="hidden" value="18:29:00" /></li>
            <li class="hidden optional" id="location_monday_close_input"><input class="close" id="location_monday_close" name="location[monday_close]" type="hidden" value="16:21:00" /></li>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks Guys!

Comment: In jquery up is not a function but you said jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***jQuery based answer***

Since you have provided the input with an id, you can use the id selector

```
$("#location_monday_close").val('');
```

If you want to get the hidden element not based on the id then you can use something like

```
$(link).closest('div.open_hours').find('input[type=hidden]').val('');
```

Also if you want to hide the div with class name open_hours, you can use

```
$("div.open_hours").hide();
```

I have re written the code for you.

```
$(function(){
    $("#anch1").click(function(){
        remove_fields ( $(this) );      
    });

    function remove_fields (link) 
    {
        var parentDiv = link.closest('div.open_hours');
        parentDiv.find('input[type=hidden]').val('');
        parentDiv.hide();
    }

});

<div class="monday">
    <div class ="open_hours">
        <li><label for="location_monday">Monday</label>
            Open: 06:29PM - 
            Close: 04:21PM 
            <a id="anch1" href="#" return false;">remove</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden optional" id="location_monday_open_input">
            <input id="location_monday_open" name="location[monday_open]" type="hidden" value="18:29:00" />
        </li>
        <li class="hidden optional" id="location_monday_close_input">
            <input class="close" id="location_monday_close" name="location[monday_close]" type="hidden" value="16:21:00" />
        </li>
    </div>    
</div>
```

***Edit***

**[next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** finds the immediately following sibling of the selector(which is the anchor tag). In your HTML there is no next sibling for the anchor tag.

Comment: $(link).closest('div.open_hours').find('input[type=hidden]').val(''); THIS WORKS! Let me ask you why does this not work: $(link).next('input[type=hidden]').val(''); ? Thanks Again! –

Comment: Please see my edit to the answer.Also I have removed the onclick from the HTML and put it inside the script.

Answer (score 3):

For prototype do this:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  var e = link.next().identify();
  $(e).setValue("");
  $(e).up(".open_hours").hide();
}
```

You need to identify/return the elements id before you can set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged both jquery and prototype, in jquery you can try like this:

```
$(link).next('input[type=hidden]').val = '';
```

Comment: ya I've tried that... for some reason that isn't working for me... 
the script will run without error (FireBug) but when I submit the form the older values are retained?